# How to get the description of a news Item from GOOGLE AJAX Feed API

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, feed, google-feed-api

I am using a script to load news from different sources, using Google AJAX feed API. How can I get the description of an entry? Below is an hello world program:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    google.load("feeds", "1");

    function initialize() {
      var feed = new google.feeds.Feed("http://news.google.com/?output=rss");
      feed.load(function(result) {
        if (!result.error) {
          var container = document.getElementById("feed");
          for (var i = 0; i < result.feed.entries.length; i++) {
            var entry = result.feed.entries[i];
            var div = document.createElement("div");
            div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(entry.title));
            container.appendChild(div);
          }
        }
      });
    }
    google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="feed"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

How can I get the description using the `entry` object??? I am using the google URL - http://news.google.com/?output=rss for RSS feeds in XML format. I want the "Description" part. How can I get that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the description, but you can't use the JSON format and the `entry` object to do it. If you read the feed parameters at https://developers.google.com/feed/v1/devguide carefully, you'll see that `description` is not a field it returns at the entry level - just at the feed level.

To do it, you need to request the feed in XML format, and then load the individual nodes, including `description`. Here's the relevant snippet I've used to do it - change the formatting etc. as you need.

```
function initialize() {
   var feed = new google.feeds.Feed("http://myblog.com/blog/feed/");
   feed.setResultFormat(google.feeds.Feed.XML_FORMAT);
   feed.load(function(result) {
   if (!result.error) {
    var items = result.xmlDocument.getElementsByTagName('item');
    item = items[0];

    //build each element
    var title = document.createElement("h4");
    title.innerHTML = item.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].firstChild.nodeValue;

    var content = document.createElement("p");
    content.innerHTML = item.getElementsByTagName('description')[0].firstChild.nodeValue;

    href = item.getElementsByTagName('link')[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

The HTML description can be retrieved by using the content variable.
Thus you should have: 
div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(entry.content));

Be aware that this will retrieve HTML data format.

Answer (score 1):

After much digging, I found that the Google API uses "contentSnippet" instead of description.  No XML formatting needed.

```
function initialize() {
    var feed = new google.feeds.Feed("http://myblog.com/blog/feed/");   
    feed.setNumEntries(10);
    feed.load(function(result) {
        if (!result.error) {

            $(document).ready(function(){   
                $('#feed-pull').append('<ul></ul>'); 
                for (var i = 0; i < result.feed.entries.length; i++) {
                    var entry = result.feed.entries[i];                     
                    var desc = entry.contentSnippet;
```

Answer (score -1):

Change entry.title in:

```
div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(entry.title));
```

to entry.description.

Comment: the description variable is undefined.